# xcodebuild generating empty .xarchive without dSYM

Tags: xcode, macos

I am building my project with the following command

```
xcodebuild -scheme 'test' -project trackingCore/timeBro.xcodeproj/ archive DSTROOT="$core" > /dev/null
```

I have set the archives path und Xcode->Preferences->Locations to a custom path. 
If i am creating an archive with Xcode everything works fine and i get a .xarchive with a dSYM.

However if i use the terminal command it creates an empty .xarchive file without a dSYM inside.

Is there something wrong with my command or my settings? 
Is the terminal command not identical?

Comment: Why `> /dev/null`?

Comment: i don't want to see all output

Comment: Maybe you want to see it if you have issues.

Comment: i have there are no issues. The package also works fine. It simply creates a .xarchive that is empty. If i do it manually in xcode it makes a not empty archive.

Comment: I consider an empty archive as an issue.

Comment: there are no issues in the packaging logs therefore i write > /dev/null